# Open Sets in Subspaces of a Metric Space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I seek some clarification in a step of the following proof of this theorem:

> *Theorem*. Let $M$ be a metric space and $(X_{\lambda})_{\lambda\in L}$ a family of connected subsets of $M$ which contain a common point $a\in M$. Then $X = \bigcup\limits_{\lambda\in L}X_{\lambda}$ are connected.

Beginning of the proof: Let $A\cup B$ a union of disjoint open subsets of $M$ such that $A\cup B = X$. The point $a$ is in one of either $A$ or $B$, say it's in $A$. **For all $\lambda\in L$, $A\cap X_{\lambda}$ and $B\cap X_{\lambda}$ are both open in $X_{\lambda}$.** Then $X_{\lambda}=(A\cap X_{\lambda})\cup(B\cap X_{\lambda})$. [...]

I didn't get why the bold part is true, could someone please explain it further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ me a metric space and $X'\subseteq X$.

Note that the $\newcommand\eps\epsilon\eps$-neighborhoods of $X'$ are *defined* by $U_\eps(x)\cap X'$ for some $\eps$-neighborhood $U_\eps(x)$ in $X$. Starting from this, can you prove the following?

> **Observation**. If $U$ is open in $X$, then $U\cap X'$ is open in $X'$.

Going away from metric spaces to topological spaces, this becomes more of a *definition* as you can see from Goodier's answer.

Answer (score 2):

For each $\lambda$, $X_{\lambda}$ has the subspace topology, so the open sets in $X_{\lambda}$ are $U\cap X_{\lambda}$, where $U$ is open in $M$. This is the definition of the subspace topology.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your answer while typing